# Vanishing/Exploding gradients in deeplearning4j

Tags: deep-learning, deeplearning4j

How to check if we're having a vanishing/exploding gradient in deeplearning4j, more specifically for recurrent neural networks? I mean, what parameters to look for and what methods should we call to get the value of such parameters?

Comment: The UI ought to show that. The DL4J community on Gitter will be able to answer this. There are 4000 devs there: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above you should take a look at the GUI, introduction [here](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-nn-visualization).

**DL4J GUI: Overview Tab -> Update:Parameter Ratios**

> The ratio of updates to parameters is specifically the ratio of mean
>   magnitudes of these values (i.e.,
>   log10(mean(abs(updates))/mean(abs(parameters)))

So, significantly high or low values may suggest exploding/vanishing gradients.

**Programmatically**

At the end of each iteration the gradients are stored in the gradient field of both ComputationalGraph and MultiLayerNetwork. It can be accessed via public gradient() method (this method does not change state, it is a simple getter), so you can analyze the gradients in your code.

Here's a small code code snippet that outputs gradients' min, average, max per variable, as well as the log10 (magnitude) of the min value:

```
    StringBuilder gradSummary = new StringBuilder("--- Gradients ---\n");
    net.gradient().gradientForVariable().forEach((var, grad) -> {
        Number min = grad.aminNumber();
        Number max = grad.amaxNumber();
        Number mean = grad.ameanNumber();
        int order = (int) Math.log10(min.doubleValue());
        gradSummary.append(var).append(": ")
            .append(min).append(",")
            .append(mean).append(",")
            .append(max).append(",")
            .append("magnitude: ").append(order).append('\n');
    });
    gradSummary.append("-----------------");
    log.info(gradSummary.toString());
```

It produces an output like the following (notice variables are named based on the layer names):

```
2019-01-05 15:26:12 INFO  --- Gradients ---
lstm-1_W: 4.1305625586574024E-11,2.102349571941886E-5,5.235217977315187E-4, magnitude: -10
lstm-1_RW: 6.30961949354969E-11,1.7203132301801816E-5,1.335109118372202E-4, magnitude: -10
lstm-1_b: 2.9782620813989524E-10,3.226526814614772E-6,3.882131932186894E-5, magnitude: -9
lstm-2_W: 2.340811988688074E-10,2.496814886399079E-5,7.095998153090477E-4, magnitude: -9
lstm-2_RW: 8.640199666842818E-11,4.6048542571952567E-5,0.0015051497612148523, magnitude: -10
lstm-2_b: 6.85293555235944E-9,3.012867455254309E-5,4.262796137481928E-4, magnitude: -8
lstm-3_W: 1.141415850725025E-10,5.7301283959532157E-5,0.0024848710745573044, magnitude: -9
lstm-3_RW: 2.446540747769177E-10,3.4060700272675604E-5,0.002297096885740757, magnitude: -9
lstm-3_b: 1.5003001507807312E-8,2.131067230948247E-5,2.356997865717858E-4, magnitude: -7
norm-1_gamma: 4.6524661456714966E-8,2.8755117455148138E-5,1.543344114907086E-4, magnitude: -7
norm-1_beta: 5.754080234510184E-7,1.0409040987724438E-4,3.460813604760915E-4, magnitude: -6
norm-1_mean: 8.82148754044465E-7,0.0033756729681044817,0.048742543905973434, magnitude: -6
norm-1_var: 3.0532873451782905E-10,2.6078732844325714E-6,1.6723810404073447E-4, magnitude: -9
dense-1_W: 3.8744474295526743E-10,5.491946285474114E-5,6.59565266687423E-4, magnitude: -9
dense-1_b: 4.4111070565122645E-6,1.4454024494625628E-4,4.0868428186513484E-4, magnitude: -5
norm-2_gamma: 2.477656607879908E-6,9.73446512944065E-5,2.708708052523434E-4, magnitude: -5
norm-2_beta: 3.106115855189273E-6,4.934889730066061E-4,0.0012065295595675707, magnitude: -5
norm-2_mean: 2.7818930902867578E-5,0.004300051834434271,0.01411475520581007, magnitude: -4
norm-2_var: 1.806318869057577E-5,0.007471780758351088,0.020012110471725464, magnitude: -4
output_W: 7.830021786503494E-8,1.4970696065574884E-4,4.896917380392551E-4, magnitude: -7
output_b: 3.1583107193000615E-4,6.765704602003098E-4,0.0011031415779143572, magnitude: -3
-----------------
```

You can even wrap this code around iteration listener, and output this once per N iterations to help babysit your training process.